# why some emails can not be reached?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I used smtpclient to send emails, but finally i found that some of the emails can not be reached.
for example: 
    receiver: aaa@123.com
sometimes, the emails we send to it , and it will receive successfully, but sometimes will not.

at the beginning, I thought it might because that smtp didn't send it successfully, then I use client.sendAsynce, and then add the event handler to handle the SendCompleted event, and i found every emails are sent out successfully, and then we check the smtp server, it really received all the emails and sent out successfully.

So the problem is why sometimes the emails will not be reached successfully, and sometimes will be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting one piece of the puzzle - the client email server. Perhaps the emails are being rejected or flagged as spam?

Comment: but why the client server didn't keep rejected it, instead sometimes it will receive the email!